# retrieving an element from an object not well typed

Tags: typescript

given an object, I want to retrieve an element from this object which has its real type instead of an union type, see my example

```js
function prop(obj: Todo, key: keyof Todo) {
    return obj[key];
}

interface Todo 
{
    id: number,
    text: string,
}
const todo : Todo = {
    id: 1,
    text: "Buy milk",
};

const id = prop(todo, "id");      // string | number instead of number
const text = prop(todo, "text");  // string | number instead of string
```

I don't understand why my variable Id and text are typed **string | number** instead of showing its real type ?

If I use a generic one of my prop method, it works, but I don't understand why it works and not my previous one

```
function prop<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K) {
     return obj[key];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the return type of your function in the first case is actually any possible type of the passed object keys. If you were to add the third field to Todo interface of type, for instance, boolean, then your function will return `string | number | boolean` and so on.

That is due to the reason that typescript doesn't get so deep into implementation of your function and expects it to return any possible key. Generic helps to establish the correspondence between the arguments. It doesn't establish the equality of `Todo` in the first and second argument.

Also your generic is missing the return type, which is `T[K]`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Daniel, the return type of my function is not any, if I hover my cursor at my variable id, it does say "string | number" and not "any". Even if I specify explicity the return type of my function with "string | number", it still show string | number.

About my generic method, even if I don't specify the return type as T[K], it show the right type for my variable "Id" and "text".

Comment: Hi! I'm not saying it's `any`, I'm saying typescript expects it to be one of all the possible types the fields of Todo interface can be.  If you were to add more properties, like boolean, objects, etc you will see how the  type of `id` will change on the last like.